# Migrating to Facebook PHP SDK v4, Open Graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having an issue migrating this particular snippet

```
// previously

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx',
));

$accessToken = $facebook->getApplicationAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$facebook->api($url, 'POST');

// v4.0
$session = Facebook\FacebookSession::newAppSession('xxx','xxx');

$response = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'POST', $url
))->execute();
```

And this is giving:

**Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: v2.0557210865'**

Comment: $url should be `/557210865` and not `557210865`

Comment: That's fixed it. Want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$url should be `/557210865` and not `557210865`.

Answer (score -1):

Open Graph API of facebook it is not good use direct access even some guys dont like it.

use python for this

from selenium import webdriver

#----

username = "my_email@email.com"
password = "123456"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\python\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://m.facebook.com/")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("m_login_email")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("m_login_password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_4")
#login_button.submit()

#----